# Nhibernate throws an exception on missing database columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Description:
We've added column

```
 alter table t_mailbox add nosticker_timespan datetime null
```

and corresponding mappings to it

```
    <hibernate-mapping assembly="GeoMail.Core" namespace="GeoMail.Core.Domain.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Mailbox" table="t_mailbox" lazy="false" >
      <id name="Id">
       <generator class="identity" />
      </id>
      ...
      <property name="NostickerPlacingDate" type="UtcDateTime">
        <column name="nosticker_timespan" sql-type="date" not-null="false" />
      </property> 
      ...
```

Everything worked perfectly. Later on we decided to remove this column in case of new conception so we deleted mapping and dropped column in database. There is no any extra relation to column "nosticker_timespan" but nhibernate throws GenericADOException on any Mailbox entity update with the reason

```
Invalid column name 'nosticker_timespan'.
```

I've cleaned all possible cached files, tried different solutions, restarted all possible services but nothing helped. Do somebody know the reason (place where this data is cached) why it happens? How to force hnibernate to recheck that this column is not present anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason! Trigger on this table in database database! Do avoid triggers!!!